# npm installs different package on server vs localhost

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running npm on my local environment. If I run `npm install` on my local environment, it will install a few packages into `node_modules/` and everything works fine.

I then pull the latest changes on the remote server server and try run `gulp` and get some errors. So I run the following:

`rm -rf node_modules
npm install
gulp`

and everything works correctly. But of course a whole bunch of items in `node_modules` have changed. So, I do a `git push` from the server, and then pull locally. But now my local build will not run `gulp` and I need to repeat the above process (remove node_modules, npm install).

Basically, it seems that `npm install` installs slightly different packages on my local environment vs server environment, despite the fact that they are both Ubuntu 14.04. The nodejs version for both server and local is also the same at `v5.3.0`.

Comment: Don't check-in `node_modules` into your git repository! This will always cause some problems between different environments, common one being compiled native code between Mac OS X and Linux. If you want to assure that same versions of modules will be used for each `npm install`, resort to [npm-shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap).

Comment: Agreed, we use Shrinkwrap to resolve such issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, we don't check in node_modules. So we run npm install and gulp on the server.